# 2 codes for input: One takes keyboard&controller, one takes only keyboard. Why? [Unity C#]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I found two sets of code that lets me steer a simple cube on a plane. The issue is that Code 1 lets me steer this with both my keyboard and my bluetooth controller (Steelseries Nimbus) and Code 2 only lets my keyboard control the cube. As I'm trying to understand C#/Unity - I'd really appreciate understanding why.
(My edit/project setting/input looks similar in both projects)

**Code 1**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        print("yo I'm a cube");
        moveSpeed = 10f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        transform.Translate(moveSpeed*Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*Time.deltaTime, 0f, -moveSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime);
         //print(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
    }
}
```

**Code 2**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    private Vector3 input;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        rb.AddForce(input * moveSpeed);
        //print(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
        //print(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    }
```

Comment: FYI: When using the print function in Code #2 (now in comment) I get confirmation that the keyboard is registered as input, and that the bluetooth controller is not registered. In Code #1 both are registered.

Comment: As long as the input is setup correctly there doesnt seem to be any obvious reason why one is keyboard only

Comment: OK, thanks for the quick reply, I will keep testing, and write if I find the answer.

Comment: Is this in the same project ? If you have identical input settings it should work exactly the same regarding input

Comment: Resetting the edit/project setting/inputs setting solved the issue. Sorry for not checking that right away.